# Can ostream overloading be a function member?

Tags: c++

I have a class `Counter` and I want to overload `operator <<` to output the data member of `Counter`. I tried to make the ostream overloading a member function:

```
Counter{
public:
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outStream, const Counter& c);
private:
    int count_;
};

std::ostream& Counter::operator<<(std::ostream& outStream, const Counter& c){
    outStream << c.count_;
    return outStream;
}
```

But the g++ compiler always outputs the same error:

> `‘std::ostream& Counter::operator<<(std::ostream&, const Counter&)’` must take exactly one argument

However, if I changed the overloading function to be a friend of the class, it worked all well, like this:

```
Counter{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outStream, const Counter& c);
private:
    int count_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outStream, const Counter& c){
    outStream << c.count_;
    return outStream;
}
```

Does this mean that the the stream operator overloading cannot be a member function of a class?

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be a friend - you can use the public interface if your class is well designed...

Comment: It has to be a friend if you want to access non-public members, just like any other function; nothing special about `operator<<` here.

Comment: @ildjarn but can it be a member function?

Comment: @Brian : No, because the first argument must be the stream, and in a member function, the first (implicit) argument is always a pointer to the class type (i.e. `this`).

Answer (score 3):

Add a `public` query method that returns the value of `count_`, then it does not have to be a `friend`:

```
Counter{
public:
    int count() const { return count_; }
private:
    int count_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outStream, const Counter& c){
    outStream << c.count();
    return outStream;
}
```

Comment: I mean..can `operator<<` be a function member of Counter?

Comment: Exposing internal members is a bad idea (this causes excessive coupling to other pieces of code). It would be better to provide a `print()` method that takes a stream as a parameter then let the object serialize itself.

Comment: @LokiAstari, internal members are not exposed here.

Comment: You are binding the interface to providing an `int` type when calling the method `count()` thus you are exposing the implementation detail count_. Getters are a horrible because of the way they tightly coupling your class with the code that uses it. Providing a print() method decouples the class as it does not expose the internal implementation.

Comment: @LokiAstari, the only change I would make is to rename the method to `value()`, or similar. The `Counter` provides some service to its client and does so via its `public` interface, otherwise it is close to useless. Having an `operator<<` that accesses the `public` interface of a class no more couples it than any other code that uses it. I dislike the suggestion of a `print()` method, due to how this would appear at a call site if more that a `Counter` instance was being output to a stream.

Comment: @hmjd: You would still use operator<< it just call print(). Read the article I link to above. This is an anti-pattern. Of course the best solution is just to make operator<< a friend as this causes the least degradation in encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the ostream operator in the class itself then it will not work the way you expect it to. It would be a member function meaning to invoke it one would have to do this: `c.operator<<("output")` which is obviously not what you mean to do. For it to work as you expect an ostream operator it must be outside the class. You can do this by making it a friend or just put it outside of the class and use getters (accessors) to output the data.

Comment: infix notation works just fine for member operators... but dispatch is done based on the left-hand operand.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be a friend, but it can't be a member.  Member operators only work when they are inside the class which corresponds to the left-hand operand.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the useful overloads for the streaming output operators ( << ) cannot be class members, because the ostream& must be on the left in use and declaration. They do not need to be friends of the class you wish to stream unless they need access to protected or private members. This means that if you can implement a streaming operator using just public functions such as observers/accessors without declaring it a friend.

In your first Counter class you are declaring a member function of the class that does not seem valid. In the second example of the Counter class you are stating that your operator overload for << , which seems valid, has access to the private members. In the second example the function must still be declared outside the class.

Wikipedia [Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) has a good list of possible operator overloads, including the in class << overloads even though they are not very useful. The in class overloads must be called backwards `CounterInstance << cout;` which is counterintuitive.